# Trying to find a comical sci-fi book, about someone brought to an alternate world by probability

Tags: story-identification, novel, humor

I would have read the book between 2000-2010, but could have been published before that, and the travelling between worlds was somehow facilitated by a dinner party.

The world the main character is sent to has lots of weird things, but all I can remember is a group of people with leather skin who only eat once a month/week?

I had a strong feeling it was called "Urth" and by Ben Elton, but I can find anything matching that searching online.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with Ben Elton, but the plot (and half-remembered title) are very close to *[Life on Urth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?17084)*, a novel from 1994 by John Kirkbride.

The story is centered on Reg and Jeanette. According to a [summary](https://gudrunlauret.com/2020/01/14/time-pieces-history-project-item-52-life-on-urth/):

> One morning, Reg comes out of his bathroom to find the rest of his
> house has disappeared. On the other side of town, Jeanette is heading
> out for the day, only to find the home beyond her bedroom has gone.
>
> By a weird coincidence, they’ve both been gone through a gap into a
> parallel universe, and find themselves on Urth, which has some
> similarities to the planet they’ve just left, but also some peculiar
> differences.

Among the people they meet are the Plainsfolk who are made out of leather, and fear being caught by humans who want to turn them into cushions. I don't recall how often the Plainsfolk eat though.

Comment: That's exactly it! I think it may have been just next to the Ben Elton books on my parents bookcase at one point. Thanks so much!

Comment: I can understand shelving it next to Elton, it has the same kind of jokey vibe